# How to edit multiple files in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim (more specifically, MacVim), if I've already set the working directory using `:cd` and I want to open all the `*.py` files within that directory, is there a way to do so from within Vim? I expected `:e *.py` would work, but got the `E77: Too many file names` error. `:help edit` doesn't seem to offer a way to open multiple files at once, only one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `args`:

For example:

```
:args /path_to_dir/*.py
```

or

```
:args /path_to_dir/**/*.py
```

`**` to match files recursively. (As suggested by @[the_velour_fog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/106525/the-velour-fog))

will open all files which has `.py` extension in the directory.

Once the files are opened use `:tab all` to put them in individual tabs.

Comment: or `:args /path_to_dir/**/*.py` for recursively descend and open files

Comment: if your files are under version control and you need to exclude files from the list you can use something like `:args \`find path/to/dir -type f -name '.git' -prune -o -name '*.py'\`` . but you need to use single quotes in the backtick expression to protect the meta characters from expansion by vim - `"` . its a tricky business because you need to prevent the arguments to `find` being expanded by both the shell **and** vim!